# Canvas editor for Xcode version 12.1 Error

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods, podfile

[image: Capture of Xcode 12.1 Canvas error]

I set up the podfile for the Xcode project and have been using the workspace file to build. "Could not build module 'GoogleDataTransport'" as well as "Umbrella header for module 'GoogleDataTransport' does not include..." errors show up when I try to use the Canvas editor. Simulator works perfectly fine but Canvas preview editor always shows build failed and the errors in the screenshot image attached to this post.